# Adding Jira comment using soap in PHP

Tags: php, soap, jira

How to add comment in Jira using SOAP in PHP?

Comment: http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#addComment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://YOUR_JIRA_DOMAIN.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login($username, $password);
$soapClient->addComment($token, $issueKey, array('body' => "your comment"));
```

**References**

- http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#addComment%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteComment%29
- https://bitbucket.org/rewbs/satellites-talk-samples/src/cd22351cf368/IssuesFromFilter.php
- http://codingx.blogspot.com/2011/04/play-with-jira-api-from-php.html
- http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA03x/Creating+a+SOAP+Client